# Simple example with Symfony2

Tags: documentation, sandbox, doctrine-orm, symfony

I read the [Symfony2 documentation](http://docs.symfony-reloaded.org/?page=learn) but i do not quite understand (how to create model, repository, configure `doctrine.orm` in `config.yml` and other simple stuffs which are easy in sf 1). So i search a small example which use Symfony2. An very simple example (like the [sandbox](http://symfony-reloaded.org/code) but little more advanced) with a page which list the content of a table with doctrine ORM and an edit/new page. I don't find nothing on GitHub! Website documentation with real example will be very helpful!
Thank you very much...

I continue my dive into sf2...

Comment: I found https://github.com/carlossg00/symfony2-jobeet

Comment: Here you can find a practical tutorial about a blog creation: http://www.dobervich.com/2011/03/05/symfony2-blog-application-tutorial-part-ii-the-data-model/

Comment: Maybe you want to look at some of this articles for help:

[Symfony2 articles](http://inchoo.net/author/darko.goles/)

Answer (score 1):

[Symfony2 Bundles](http://symfony2bundles.org/) is a valuable source of Symfony2-based applications and 3rd-party bundles.

However, you should keep in mind that lots of project you can find out there is out-dated as Sf2 is still not stable and its API is changed quite often.

Basically, all you have to do is:

1. Ensure that Doctrines' bundles are enabled in your `ApplicationKernel`.
2. Make sure it's configured properly:

   ```
   doctrine.dbal:
       driver:   pdo_pgsql
       host:     127.0.0.1
       user:     root
       password: password
       dbname:   my_database
       charset:  utf8

   doctrine.orm:
       mappings:
           MyApplicationBundle:  ~
           SomeThirdPartyBundle: ~
   ```
3. Create some entities.
4. Although you could use Doctrine2 repositories I'm not a big fan of them. IMO it's better to create your own managers (they can use original repositories) that will provide a transparent API. You shouldn't identify your model layer as ORM only. You could check out [UserBundle by FriendsOfSymfony](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/UserBundle) as their approach is pretty good.

Final usage:

```
$posts = $this->get('myapp.post_manager')->findRecentlyUsed(new \DateTime('-1 week'));

return $this->render('MyApp:Post:list.html.twig', array(
    'posts' => $posts
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony DIC and config has changed!

You should now use sth like this in your config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_pgsql
        host:     127.0.0.1
        user:     root
        password: password
        dbname:   my_database
        charset:  utf8

    orm:
        mappings:
            MyApplicationBundle:  ~
            SomeThirdPartyBundle: ~
```